# How to post an attribute value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an enum:

```
public enum EffectType
{
    None,
    Positve,
    Negative
}
```

I've three divs:

```
<div id="divNone"></div>
<div id="divPositive"></div>
<div id="divNegative"></div>
```

After the user clicks one of these three, the markup will be:

```
<div id="divNone"></div>
<div id="divPositive" class="selected"></div>
<div id="divNegative"></div>
```

How do I post the selected div and identity the selected `EffectType` in the controller so I can save the value to the data store?

Comment: Why don't you use radio button for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would associate some data with the element that you can lookup when the click event happens:

```
<div id="divNone" data-effect-type="0" class="effectType selected">

$('#someButton').click(function()
{
     var effectType = $('.effectType').find('.selected').data('effect-type');

     $.ajax({
         ...
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery post ,

```
$.post('controler/YourAction',{effectType:$('div.selected').attr('id')},function(data){

});
```

And in your action,

```
Public ActionResult YourAction(string effectType){
   return view();
}
```